# How to run an Rmd shiny markdown doc from online repo?

Tags: r, github, shiny, knitr, r-markdown

I have an interactive knitr/rmarkdown doc that uses shiny apps.
I want to place the .Rmd file on either my personal site or GitHub.

**How would I be able to remotely run this file directly from online?**

For example, when I run the Rmd file from my local machine, I use

```
rmarkdown::run("./IntroToShinyWorkshop.Rmd")
```

But when I try to run a file form online I get an error that the path doesn't exist (w/ one of the issues being that it merges the url with my wd).

```
run("IntroToShinyWorkshop.Rmd",dir = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/theforestecologist/ShinyWorkshop/master/")
```

> Error in run("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/theforestecologist/ShinyWorkshop/master/IntroToShinyWorkshop.Rmd") : 
>     The directory 'C:/Users/theforestecologist/Documents/https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/theforestecologist/ShinyWorkshop/master' does not exist
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
>     path[1]="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/theforestecologist/ShinyWorkshop/master": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

---

**Related**: Once I *do* figure out how to run a file from an online repo, I'm also interested in how to change the working directory to that url so that I can utilize other files there.

- For example, I have a wrapper function (.R file) I can source that will call my .Rmd file (instead of running the Rmd file directly) -- however, I get the error that I cannot change the wd in my wrapper function to access the .Rmd file online.

Comment: I've also tried using `includeMarkdown("https://....file_name.Rmd")` in a shiny app, which will get the Rmd file to run/render from an online repo, but fails to actually generate any of the internal shiny apps within the rmarkdown rmd file when rendered :(.

Comment: This should walk you through it: https://github.com/opetchey/RREEBES/wiki/Reading-data-and-code-from-an-online-github-repository

Comment: Did you ever figure it out @theforestecologist